# Postgresql does not accept \0 in UTF string, while C# does

Tags: c#, postgresql, utf-8

I have some data that includes a `\0` byte in it, and that seems to be valid UTF8 data:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        byte[] b = new byte[3];
        b[0] = 65;
        b[1] = 66;
        b[2] = 0;
        
        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(b));
    }
}
```

That code [works fine](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8XhUiS). But, when trying to update a record in Postgres, it complains about it:

> 22021: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00

The data shouldn't be there, but how can it be that one system accepts it, and another doesn't? I reckon they both implement standards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From documenation 
[8.3. Character Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/datatype-character.html)

> ```
> +-----------------------------------+----------------------------+
> |               Name                |        Description         |
> +-----------------------------------+----------------------------+
> | character varying(n), varchar(n)  | variable-length with limit |
> | character(n), char(n)             | fixed-length, blank padded |
> | text                              | variable unlimited length  |
> +-----------------------------------+----------------------------+
> ```
>
> The characters that can be stored in any of these data types are determined by the database character set, which is selected when the database is created. **Regardless of the specific character set, the character with code zero (sometimes called NUL) cannot be stored.** For more information refer to Section 23.3.

Comment: Thanks, the resulting message is a bit confusing though. It looks like the code point is invalid, not that it is not allowed.

Comment: Also for some background read this: https://www.commandprompt.com/blog/null-characters-workarounds-arent-good-enough/